# raise HTTPException(response, data) discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

Tags: discord

I started making a simple video bot, but I ran into many problems, I seem to have solved them.
But this remains: raise HTTPException(response, data) discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized.
After starting the bot, this is nonsense, how to solve it? I have no experience in python, I only saw it (no basics).
Here is my code:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because of your token format
`token = ('your token')[1:-1]` will return nothing so
do this:

```
token = 'your token here'
client.run(token)
```